# Hiding HTML elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im using the after property on my h2s to create border lines.

Im using the border lines on my home page and parent page but don't want them on my sub pages is there anyway to display none for this?

thanks

Comment: Please share some code that you have written. Without seeing your code and what you have attempted, it is hard to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what code you have written but to give you an idea, you can do the following:

`<span class="border-line">Some text here</span>`

Then in your CSS

```
.border-line {
  display: none
}
```

Comment: So i'm using the after class to create my border lines under the H2 Titles. for example :h2:after {
    height: 3px;
    display: block;
    width: 182px;
    background: #D3075E;
    border: 1px white;
    content: '';
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative; } I'm just wanting this on the homepage and parent page is there any way of doing this without having another style sheet?. I'm also trying to change my slider dots to a font awesome icon but i'm struggling to do this, I have seen how to do it with arrows but not dots. any ideas? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

it simply throw the styling in another style sheet and then link it to your homepage and parent page but not to your other pages it should solve the problem